# Plugging noise into bump is causing texture to show bump colors

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, bump

I have two bumps strung together, and no matter which way I string them, when I plug the noise into either bump node, it shows colors you would see when plugging bump into albedo, you know, the rainbow-ish colors? Anyway, its not even how you would think based on the uv map. its just red yellow and green, with a massive grey spot. A fix would be greatly appreciated. I've tried everything I can think of. Using an image, which just showed the albedo of the image, re-making the bump, because sometimes the bump node was created weirdly and so it wasn't functioning correctly, and I've obviously restarted blender and my computer. I've also tried switching render engines to see if that would help, it didn't.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Do you mind adding a screenshot of your shader? Also please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: Have you tried the latest version?

Comment: It should work fine unless you plug the output of one into the height of another.